# How to make number of slides TOTALLY responsive (bxslider 4.1) without having to reload the page

Tags: jquery-plugins, bxslider

Desperately trying to change the number of slides in order for the carousel slides totally responsive (INSTEAD OF having to refresh the page to show updated number of min/max slides.

Please help!!! I've been fighting with it all day.

Right now, I have to refresh the browser to show correct number of slides.
Here is my code:

```
    $(window).ready(function(){
        var minNumber,
            maxNumber,
            width = $(window).width();

        if (width < 430) {
            minNumber = 1;
            maxNumber = 2;
        } else if (width < 1024) {
            minNumber = 3;
            maxNumber = 3;
        } else {
            minNumber = 4;
            maxNumber = 5;
        }

        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            minSlides: minNumber,
            maxSlides: maxNumber,
            slideWidth: 515,
            slideMargin: 0
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(window).ready(function(){` this function only runs once when the `window` fires it's `ready` event.  Though creating what you are after might be more complex than rebuilding a slideshow every time the window re-sizes

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know I could just set minNumber at 1, and set maxNumber at 5, but it's not actually responsive on the screen. (image boxes are cut off at the right side of the screen). There has to be a way to get the full on effect of a responsive carousel...

Answer (score 0):

u don't need use jquery to switch number of elements:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 4,
        slideWidth: 515,
        slideMargin: 0
    });
```

bxSlider is then responsive. because if u change width he making carusel 1-4 element inside